# Como controlar un proceso pesado en un command

Tags: email, symfony

Necesito mandar cientos o miles de correos con o sin archivos adjuntos. Para ello he pensado usar un ContainerAwareCommand que puedo lanzar desde el cron y para monitorizarlo usar la misma consola o que guarde ciertos valores en bd en cada iteración.

Hay alguna forma de detener o pausar un command ? puedo tener un mayor control o interactuar?

Hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo o monitorizarlo ?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es relativamente sencilla, tienes que usar logs, dejar un registro por ejemplo de los mails que ha sido enviados o cuales ha fallado, si usas symfony, ya viene integrado (depende de la versión) monolog que hace casi todo el trabajo por ti.

Toda la información de como hacerlo la pueden encontrar acá:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html

Luego cuando tengas los logs el como leerlos ya es otro tema que puede ser más complejo, imagino que para empezar puedes simplemente usar un tail -f (si usas linux o mac) para ver las últimas lineas de archivo y como se va escribiendo.

Ssludos,